# Shuffling array.Output not correct

Tags: java

I have been working on this program and randomly shuffles the contents of an array of integers.

This is what is supposed to look like:

Array contents:   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? y

Array contents:   5 12  7 10  6  9 15  1 13  3  4 11 14  2  8
Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? y

Array contents:   2  9 15  4 12 11  3  7 10  8  1  6 13  5  14

### Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? n

This is what im getting:

Array Contents: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? y

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "y"

### and says build failed

This is the main code:

```
public class Evao1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            Scanner kp = new Scanner(System.in);
             final int size = 15;
        char q = 'y';
        boolean flag = false;

        Shuffler myShuffler = new Shuffler(size);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(;;) {
        myShuffler.display();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Do you wish to shuffle these numbers? ");

        String value = input.next();
        if (value.equals("q")) break;
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the additional class:

```
public class Shuffler {
    private int[] data;

    public Shuffler(int size){
        data = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i + 1;
        }

    }

    public void shuffle(){
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random(15);

            int second = r.nextInt(15) + 1;
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[second];
            data[second] = temp;
        }

    }

    public void display()
    {

        String values = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            if (i < 15)
            {
                values += (i + 1);
                if (i < 14)
                {
                    values += ", ";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Array Contents: %s \n", values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please expand on `"FAILS"`. Fails in what way? It says nasty things to you  and makes you write bad checks?

Comment: int value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);, your input is 'y', y is not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the last two lines of your `for` loop in the `Evao1` class.

First, I think you meant to write `if (value.equals("n")) break;`

Second, instead of `int value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);`
Just do `myShuffler.shuffle();`

Also, in the `for` loop of `display()` you aren't actually displaying anything from the `data` array.
Change `values += (i + 1);` to `values += data[i];`

Comment: wow what an obvious mistake.Thanks. Its just not shuffling though.Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: I added the fix for that to my answer.